# Usage of Bearer Tokens in https request

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to connect to an API using 'auth' in the options. Currently it looks like this:

```
var options = {        
hostname: '<name of site>',
        port: 443,
        path: '<path>',
        auth:'Bearer <Token>',
        method: 'GET'
};
```

However, I get Status Code 403 if I execute the request. When I put the following URL in the browser, it works:

```
https://<Host Name+ Path>?authorization=Bearer%20<Token>
```

I've already tried to change auth into `Authorization=Bearer <Token>` and `Authorisation:Bearer <Token>` but it didn't changed anything.

I'm probably just setting up the authorisation part not correctly, but couldn't find any info how `auth` works

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Add auth to header in this way

```html
var options = {        
        hostname: '<name of site>',
        port: 443,
        path: '<path>',
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{
            Authorization: ' Bearer <Token>'            
       }
};
```

Comment: This results in `403 Missing authorization` 
With my code I had `403 Invalid authorisation`

Sadly didn't helped me

Comment: Can you provide mo information about this API.  Any documentation? And code of you app

Comment: This is the API I'm using: (https://developer.clashofclans.com). In order to see the documentation you have to sign up.

Comment: as I see in doc
correct way - 

 headers:{
            Authorization: ' Bearer <Token>'
        }

Comment: @WernerderChamp You are wellcome

Answer (score 0):

`auth:'Bearer <Token>'` should be header, not query